# Concatenation of an input value and String variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am trying to concatenate the value of the input with the String variable. For instance:
(lets say that the input with an id 'input1' has the value of 'tttttt')

```
var test = 'blabla' + $('#input1').val() + 'blabla';
```

So the expected result (at least for me) should be `'blablattttttblabla'`.
The problem is that it does not insert the value of that input in the middle so the result is `'blablablabla'`.
Does someone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that `.val()` returns an empty string. Are you sure that field is there and it's the only one with that id?

Comment: Try executing `$('#input1').val()` in the console and see what the result is.

Comment: whats the value of `$('#input1').val()` by itself?  My guess is that your selector is wrong.

Comment: that looks like it should be working. are you getting an error? most likely if your not then you have a scope issue and your trying to concat before `input1` has a value. can you show the scope in which this is being called?

Comment: does `$('#input1').length` return 1

Comment: my best guess is , your DOM element is not an input but its a DIV or a SPAN in which case you might want to use .html() instead of .val()

Comment: Ahhh, my mistake, sorry guys to post such an irrelevant question. I dont keep my code clean and I did not see that I put it out of the button click function. Anyway thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try**

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="input1" value="ttttttt"/>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var test = 'blabla' + $('#input1').val() + 'blabla';
    alert(test);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

What it seems to me is that either you are missing a jQuery library at the top or this script is not called in the `doc ready` handler:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function () {
      var test = 'blabla' + $('#input1').val() + 'blabla';
      alert(test);
   });
</script>
```

#### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dCSPR/)

Be sure that your `#input1` has a value contained in.