# How to append "given text" with a textarea when send button is clicked.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, buttonclick

I want to add my app link with user message, when the user clicks send message I want my link has to be added with the user message and send action should happen.

Eample: if user typed "Hi Jhon" and press 'send' button
the Sent message should be "HI Jhon www.yahoo.co.in"

This is the code:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.btn.btn-md.im_submit.im_submit_send', function (e) { }
```

But before I concat inside this block,the send action has been triggered and the original val without link has been sent.

Javascript or jQuery any answers are appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some relevant code?

Comment: submit the form with AJAX to prevent page refresh and append the message - alternatively have a success function from the AJAX call that changes the text accordingly

Comment: Sorry but this seems to be very basic problem. Have you googled it yet?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685132/concatenation-of-an-input-value-and-string-variable

Comment: This is the code:  jQuery(document).on('click', '.btn.btn-md.im_submit.im_submit_send', function (e) {
}  But before i concat inside this block,the send action has been triggered and the original val without link has been sent.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// first we build textarea box for user type
var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
textarea.style.display="block";
textarea.innerHTML = "Type A Message";

// next we need to use some very important algorithms
// and math to create a button here
var buttonText = "Click me to send MeSSaGE";
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = "<b>"+buttonText+"</b>";
btn.style.color = "green";
var doImportantMath = function(){btn.style.color = btn.style.color === "green" ? "purple" : "green"; };
btn.style.opacity = "0.7";

// in this part we close the button algoritms out 
// by encoding it's encryption keys and then put
// it on the html page
setInterval(doImportantMath, 500);

// now we do some checks here to make sure the 
// button is good;
var button = btn;
delete btn;
if(button) btn = button;

// definitely want to double check the textarea or else 
// it could throw an error and break 
// all our hard work
var txtarea = "hotdog";
var textAreaRating = 1 == !0 && true ? 78 : 43;
if(textAreaRating > 50) txtarea = textarea;

// create a place to put our elements
var box = document.createElement("div");
box.style.background = "url(http://top10hm.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Megan-Fox1.jpg)";
box.style.width = "400px";
box.style.height = "300px";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(box);
box.appendChild(textarea);
box.appendChild(btn);
textarea.style.opacity = "0.7";
textarea.style.width = "90%";
box.style.textAlign = "center";
box.style.margin = "1em auto";

// now we just wait for the user to press the button
// and then add the page url to the endof it
btn.onclick = function(){
    textarea.value = textarea.value+" "+window.location.href
};
```

Comment: thank you @I wrestled a bear once.   i need to append this "message/link" in telegram web, so am listening to the the "Send" button of Telegram. One the event is triggered, before we do the concatenation, the message transmission happened by some other method behind. i want to stop the action of that method too. How to do that. 'jQuery(document).on('click', '.btn.btn-md.im_submit.im_submit_send', function (e)'
                    {
                    'var textAreaBox =document.querySelector('textarea.form-control');' 'textAreaBox.value = textarea.value+" "+window.location.href'

Comment: call the `preventDefault()` method of the event that is passed to the submit handler

Comment: 'jQuery(document).on('click', 'button', function (e)'
                    '{  e.preventDefault()  }'   Will this work

Comment: you have a few too many quotes `jQuery(document).on('click', 'button', function (e){ e.preventDefault(); }`

Comment: This code not stopping the send action. @ I wrestled a bear once.

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md im_submit im_submit_send" ng-class="draftMessage.type == 'edit' ? 'im_submit_edit' : 'im_submit_send'">
                        <span class="im_submit_send_label nocopy" my-i18n="im_submit_message" data-content="Send"></span>
                        <span class="im_submit_edit_label nocopy" my-i18n="im_submit_edit_message" data-content="Save"></span>
                      </button>

Comment: Above was the HTML code for the button in "Telegram" webPage.

Comment: @JebaMoses - that is an entirely different question than the one you asked. if my answer was helpful please click the upvote and/or checkmark to accept the answer and ask a new question. feel free to tag me and i'll come answer that one too.

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once. I Voted your answer, just after viewing it. Really thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var userInput = ~~;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: YOUR URL,
  data: JSON.stringify({ message: `${userInput} www.yahoo.co.in` })
})
```

``` `` ``` is called **Template String**, which enables you to interpolate variables inside the string.
More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Or you can use this:

```
var message = $('#input').val() + 'www.yahoo.co.in';

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: YOUR URL,
  data: JSON.stringify({ message: message })
})
```

Just add string value next to your variable.

Comment: Please add explanation. Not everyone knows what `` means

Comment: @Rajesh Modified. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sent').on('click', function(){
var userInput =  $('#your-input').val();
var messageToSent = userInput + yourAppLink;
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://your url ',
        data: messageToSent
        success: function (response) {
        //do your post-logic here
        }
});
```

This is try to concat your app link to the value that user inputted to text area, by jquery. And prepared data before you submitting. This might help to you.

Comment: Please add explanation. Why will it help. Why is it different from other answers. What is the benefit of this approach.

Comment: thank you @Aung Satt, but the default send action triggered before these concatenation and posting to textArea finished.